# How to change the number style language in numbering for MS Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, language, styles, numbering

I have MS Word 2010 and I want to make numbering words on Arabic [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXFjv.png)

[image: 1]

for example in one, two, three or first, second...
I wanted to be in Arabic for numbing chapter in my basic language.
I tried to install the Arabic language pack for MS Office 2010 from the Microsoft website, but it didn't work even when I change the interface language to Arabic.

It only show numbers and words in English.

**And note:**
My windows version is in English.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to change either your Windows language, or the language of the Word interface. Installing the [Arabic Office Language Pack](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/language-accessory-pack-for-office-82ee1236-0f9a-45ee-9c72-05b026ee809f?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252fOffice-language-interface-pack-LIP-downloads-d63007c2-e8ae-41fd-8bfb-fce2857010e1&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#ID0EAADAAA=Office_2010) should be enough.

Make sure you download the version that matches your version of Office 2010 (32bit/64/bit).

To make sure everything has been installed properly, make sure that Arabic appears in the list of languagues (File->Options->Languages).

[Language Pack List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLJL3.png)

If everything has been installed correctly, the Arabic number lists should appear under "Define New Number Format":

[Arabic number format available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6YSl.png)

If it's still not available, you may need to reinstall Office + the language pack.